# What animals can distinguish or recognize musical chords of like 2 notes?

Tags: scales

I was just thinking if [bird chirps fit into a musical scale in any case](https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/bgjbcw/do_birds_chirp_in_a_certain_scale/), so not sure about that. But what I'm wondering here is what animals "respond to" a pair of notes on the major or minor scale, like major third, minor third, perfect fifth, etc.. Just 2 notes for now, could go into 3 note chords if there's a lot of research.

But who has looked into this, is there anything of interest here? Like, for example, do dogs or rats or guinea pigs "like" major third chords, and "dislike" minor third chords, or dissonant vs. "pleasant" chords of 2 notes. By like/dislike, maybe there were some experiments where they learned to recognize or be stimulated by these sounds in some ways. Curious what the research is at a high level, and a key place to look further.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question; currently, there could be a new answer posted for each animal species, and endless list-type question are not allowed.

Comment: I don't think this question is really [on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although it is an interesting premise, this is both outside the scope of Music.SE and ultimately a list question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Research has been done on this; this is a new topic for me, but I was able to find [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5564495/): *Paola Crespo-Bojorque and Juan M. Toro, "The use of interval ratios in consonance perception by rats (Rattus norvegicus) and humans (Homo sapiens)"*  Two-note chords are used to investigate the perception of consonance in rats.  From the abstract:

> ...several comparative studies have tackled the question of how general the perception of consonance and dissonance of musical chords is across species.

> Research has shown that Japanese monkeys (Macaca fuscata, Izumi, 2000), Java sparrows (Padda oryzivora, Watanabe, Uozumi, & Tanaka, 2005), European starlings (Sturnus vulgaris, Hulse, Bernard, & Braaten, 1995), black-capped chickadees (Poecile atricapillus, Hoeschele, Cook, Guillette, & Brooks, 2012), and pigeons (Columbia livia, Brooks & Cook, 2009), are able to discriminate across chords, and this capacity may be based on sensory consonance. In parallel, different neural responses have been observed for consonant and dissonant stimuli in macaque monkeys (Macaca fascicularis, Fishman et al., 2001).

So, Humans are not unique in their ability to differentiate chords, and may not be unique in the perception of "consonance" and "dissonance" either.  There are plenty of citations in that paper that link to other research on the same topic, if you wish to explore.  There is even research being done to see if various animals *prefer* certain chords.  Notably, [*Koda et al. 2013*](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23566027/) and [*McDermott & Hauser, 2004*](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15582619/) investigate using two-note chords as you suggested.  These studies did not find preference for consonance in their subjects (Tamarins and Campbell's monkeys).

Comment: Amazing! Can you briefly add what they mean by "discriminate" the sounds, I'll take a look into the papers though, thanks.

Comment: "Discriminating" between two sounds simply means that they can tell the difference.  In this particular paper, rats were trained to press a lever, and the rats were rewarded with food for pressing the correct lever.  The idea is that if the rats can tell the difference between the consonant and dissonant tones, they will likely learn to press the correct lever for the reward.  Other experiments may use slightly different approaches.

Comment: Being really picky, *dyads* is a better label than *chords* - for me.